# Problems related to magento invoicing

Tags: magento-1.7, invoice, pdf, print

I have a website running on magento i m facing some issues on my site can any person help me in rectifying the issues......

```
When i m trying to get print of invoice from admin panel in magento m getting error .

**Trace:
0 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory.php(54): Zend_Pdf_Resource_Image_Png->__construct('/home/content/3...')
1 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/Zend_Pdf_Image.php(124): Zend_Pdf_Resource_ImageFactory::factory('/home/content/3...')
2 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract.php(158): Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath('/home/content/3...')
3 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice.php(123): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract->insertLogo(Object(Zend_Pdf_Page), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Store))
4 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice.php(119): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice->getPdf(Array)
5 /home/content/30/11052930/html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/Order/InvoiceController.php(489): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Sales_Invoice->printAction()
6 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/__default.php(13589): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_InvoiceController->printAction()
7 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/__default.php(17934): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('print')
8 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/__default.php(17491): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
9 /home/content/30/11052930/html/includes/src/__default.php(20068): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
10 /home/content/30/11052930/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
11 /home/content/30/11052930/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
12 {main}
```

Error log record number: 1632019843**

Can any 1 tell how to rectify this error.

```
How can i change the format of invoice. changing the logo and text to be displayed on invoice.
```

Please help me i in big trouble. I'm having loss on daily basis because of these small issue in my website.

**1. Message which is showing is "Only non-interlaced images are currently supported".
2. Logo already exists.**

---

In admin panel when i click on invoices and open previous invoice. Then click on print it shows this error. But send email feature is working fine it is sending email to mail id mentioned.
Can you please also guide me how to change the format of invoice.

Comment: Convert the logo image in .jpeg format and it will work.

Comment: @Abhijeetkumarsharma it seems there is a certain format that works invoices. I followed your advice and switched from png to jpg and it worked. Some jpg showed a black square though, then I use Export As in Photoshop (instead of Save As) and it worked fine. Thanks.